# Mongoose: Vritual getter of populated document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 schemas and `schema2` is populating field from `schema1` which has a virtual getter. But that virtual getter is not appearing when I populate from `schema2`.

example code:

```js
schema1 = new Schema({
  comments: [{ type: Array }],
})

schema1.virtual('comment_count').get(function() {
    return this.comments.length
})

schema2 = new Schema({
  post: { type: String },
  people: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'schema1' }
})
```

assuming `schema2`'s model is `schema2model`

```js
schema2model.find({}).populate('people')
```

here i do get `comments` property but I'm not getting `comment_count` field

Comment: Use capital in first letter of reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There are few ways to access virtual properties, try anything:

1. Access manually

```
var docs = schema2model.find({}).populate('people');
console.log(docs[0].people.comment_count);
```

2. Access using [toObject](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) method

```
var docs = schema2model.find({}).populate('people');
docs = docs.toObject({ virtuals: true });
console.log(docs);
```

3. set `toObject: { virtuals: true }` property in your schema

```
let schema1 = new Schema({
  comments: [{ type: Array }]
}, { toObject: { virtuals: true } });
```

- call your query after updating your schema

```
var docs = schema2model.find({}).populate('people');
console.log(docs);
```

Comment: what about `.lean()` ?

Comment: you will not access virtual properties when you use `lean()`,